# Sequential use of shared variable in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, shared-memory, event-dispatch-thread

I am working on a java GUI application. On some event (eg. button click) I want to read large ammount of data from a file in a new worker thread and store it into shared variable. Then from this worker thread I want to invoke EDT (Event Dispatching Thread) and use the data.

There is no concurrent accesing of the data - just create the data in one thread and when finished, use it in another thread.

I am not sure if invoking EDT from worker thread makes sure that EDT will see the updated data or if it is possible that EDT will only work with some old cashed version.

I don't want to get into using volatile fields and synchronised collections because of the complicated structure of my data class and because I don't want to make my code any slower using unnecessary synchronization.

pseudocode example:

```
EDT: MyType data;

EDT: start new Worker thread;
Worker: loadDataFromFileInNewThread(data);
Worker: invokeEDT; //using java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater
EDT: use data;
```

Is this usage of shared memory alright or do I have to force EDT to use updated version somehow?

Comment: It's a shame that this isn't properly documented. I'd expect it to work fine. But to be sure, you could simply indeed update a volatile variable or an AtomicReference. Reading a volatile variable won't have any significant performance impact on the application. Reading a large file : like going on the moon and come back. Reading an AtomicReference: like blinking the eyes.

Comment: you can use future, and executer to get you data in the future object, this will give you the ability to know when your data is read completely in the worker thread, so you can what ever you want in it

Comment: FYI, invokeLater doesn't _start_ the EDT.  The EDT already is running, waiting for events.  That must be the case because your program already has handled a button click.  When you want the EDT to do something, you _post an event_.  The invokeLater() method posts a general-purpose, non-GUI-related event that basically means _do this..._.

Comment: james -- I mostly I agree.  Point of pedantry though:  invokeLater would start the EDT if nothing AWT-related had been performed in his program up to that point.  As you note though, if his worker is launched in response to an AWT button click, then obviously the AWT-EDT is already started at the point the worker calls invokeLater.

Comment: james - ofcourse, just poor choice of words, kinda offtopic anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the worker thread, calling `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` ultimately locks `java.awt.EventQueue.pushPopLock` before enqueueing your Runnable. This means your worker synchronized on that lock at this point.

On the EDT side of things, the EDT is in a loop calling `java.awt.EventQueue.getNextEvent` to receive and process work.  `getNextEvent` locks `java.awt.EventQueue.pushPopLock` before dequeueing your Runnable.

At this point we know that both your worker thread and the EDT have both synchronized on the same object, which creates a memory flush point between the two threads, according to the JMM.

Thus, in your specific scenario, you do not need additional synchronization or `volatile` to guarantee that the EDT sees up-to-date information created by your worker thread -- as long as your worker thread stops modifying the shared data after having called `invokeLater` (which would be a best practice anyway).

Implementation detail: Older versions of Java do not use a `java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock`, but rather use the `synchronized` method flag on the EventQueue's methods.  However, the exact same rules apply as described above with the Lock.

Comment: I just wonder: does this apply to workerThread1->workerThread2 relation or only worker->EDT?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use a `SwingWorker` for your asynchronous loading task as it simplifies synchronization with the EDT and provides some hooks for sending periodically updates to the EDT (e.g. for progress reporting):

```
// should only be accessed by the EDT
MyData myData;

class MyDataLoder extends SwingWorker<MyData, Object> {
    @Override
    public MyData doInBackground() {
        // this method runs in a background thread
        // do loading of data here
        // update progress periodically: setProgress(...);

        return loadedData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        // called after doInBackground completes
        // runs in EDT
        try {
            // publish your data to the EDT
            myData = get();
        } catch (Exception ignore) { }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the data is handed over to the EDT in the `done()` method. This method is called in the EDT, and there the data is safely "pulled" from the background thread to the EDT via `get()`, so it is safely published to the EDT.

As a nice side-effect, you can bind some progress bar to the `progress` property of the `SwingWorker` - so you can display loading progress.

Comment: I considered SwingWorker but it is a no go - i need the task to be repeatable and creating new SwingWorkers is limited to 10, plus finished SwingWorker just hangs for 10 minutes until it's disposed (regulal thread seems like a better option most of the time)

Comment: @Abdul I understand. Never heard about that 10 minutes issue. But I think you can still take the main idea - having a background thread doing the work - best done via `ExecutorService` - and publishing the result via EDT. So you'll have to do your own `invokeLater(this::done)` - no big deal.